# Initializing mediaelement.js without using jquery

Tags: javascript, mediaelement

I roll my own javascript and don't use jquery.

I'd like to run mediaelement.js without jquery.

I've tried a few different methods and when I test in FF with an MP3,which needs the flash player it throws an error:

TypeError:this.node is undefined
line 76 media-and-player.min.js

Here is my attempt right from the example with the files base hrefed off of mediaelementjs.com:

http://guidedimagerydownloads.com/test_mediaelement.html

What did I miss? Is there a complete audio element example without jquery online?

Not so easy tracing someone elses javascript that has been compressed!

I love the idea of the project, just sans jquery (for myself) please...

Comment: JQuery is written to take care of the vagaries of different browsers.

Comment: jQuery is written to troll the competent